Bitbake failing to fetch raspberry kernel inside docker
I'm currently trying to build a Raspberry Pi image with Yocto Nanbield in a Docker container hosted on Windows.
The general setup works fine, and I'm getting bitbake to start, but it eventually fails to get the Raspberry Pi Linux kernel. I've tried to change some git configs as mentioned by others, but nothing really seems to work for me. I also changed the Yocto versions from Kirkstone to Nanbield, but there was also no improvement there.
Using a Debian Bullseye image to run:
RUN mkdir -p $YOCTO_DIR && cd $YOCTO_DIR && mkdir sources && cd sources && \
    git clone https://git.yoctoproject.org/poky -b nanbield && \
    git clone https://git.yoctoproject.org/meta-raspberrypi -b nanbield && \
    git clone https://git.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded -b nanbield

RUN cd $YOCTO_DIR && source sources/poky/oe-init-build-env && \
    git config --global http.postBuffer 52428800 && git config --global core.compression 0 && \
    git config --global url."https://github.com/".insteadOf git@github.com: && \
    git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git:// && \
    bitbake-layers add-layer ../sources/meta-raspberrypi \
                             ../sources/meta-openembedded/meta-oe \
                             ../sources/meta-openembedded/meta-multimedia \ 
                             ../sources/meta-openembedded/meta-networking \
                             ../sources/meta-openembedded/meta-python && \
    echo 'MACHINE ?= "raspberrypi4"' >> conf/local.conf && \
    echo 'LICENSE_FLAGS_ACCEPTED = "synaptics-killswitch"' >> conf/local.conf && \
    bitbake core-image-base

This eventually fails with the following error:
894.5 WARNING: linux-raspberrypi-1_6.1.61+git-r0 do_fetch: Failed to fetch URL git://github.com/raspberrypi/linux.git;name=machine;branch=rpi-6.1.y;protocol=https, attempting MIRRORS if available 
904.7 ERROR: linux-raspberrypi-1_6.1.61+git-r0 do_fetch: Fetcher failure: Fetch command export PSEUDO_DISABLED=1; export PATH="/home/notroot/yocto/build/tmp/sysroots-uninative/x86_64-linux/usr/bin:/home/notroot/yocto/sources/poky/scripts:/home/notroot/yocto/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi4-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-raspberrypi/6.1.61+git/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi:/home/notroot/yocto/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi4-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-raspberrypi/6.1.61+git/recipe-sysroot/usr/bin/crossscripts:/home/notroot/yocto/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi4-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-raspberrypi/6.1.61+git/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/sbin:/home/notroot/yocto/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi4-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-raspberrypi/6.1.61+git/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin:/home/notroot/yocto/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi4-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-raspberrypi/6.1.61+git/recipe-sysroot-native/sbin:/home/notroot/yocto/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi4-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-raspberrypi/6.1.61+git/recipe-sysroot-native/bin:/home/notroot/yocto/sources/poky/bitbake/bin:/home/notroot/yocto/build/tmp/hosttools"; export HOME="/home/notroot"; LANG=C git -c gc.autoDetach=false -c core.pager=cat clone --bare --mirror https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux.git /home/notroot/yocto/build/downloads/git2/github.com.raspberrypi.linux.git --progress failed with exit code 128, no output
904.7 ERROR: linux-raspberrypi-1_6.1.61+git-r0 do_fetch: Bitbake Fetcher Error: FetchError('Unable to fetch URL from any source.', 'git://github.com/raspberrypi/linux.git;name=machine;branch=rpi-6.1.y;protocol=https')
904.8 NOTE: recipe linux-raspberrypi-1_6.1.61+git-r0: task do_fetch: Failed
904.9 ERROR: Task (/home/notroot/yocto/sources/meta-raspberrypi/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-raspberrypi_6.1.bb:do_fetch) failed with exit code '1'

When running the same build on a native debian machine, everything works fine and the build completes without issues.
EDIT:
Building the docker image in a machine with better network bandwidth seems to solve the issue with the fetcher job and the build succeeds, which is a bit of an unsatisfying solution to the problem.

maybe related to ssh key missing ?

have you tried to provide "rev=" instead of branch? do it with "nobranch=1" altogether

@OlegKokorin do you mean editing the bitbake recipes to use the revisions instead of branches?

it's appeared, most of the QT based recipes are pointing to the "release" git branches now.
release git branches allow no dedicated commit cloning/checkout in case if release branch has been specified.
the only stable working option being found so far is to disable branch request during recipe clone action.
in case of QT, all recepies are depending on qt5-git.inc file, where the QT_MODULE_BRANCH_PARAM is synthesized. it is optional and can be overriden in the local.conf with the
QT_MODULE_BRANCH_PARAM = "nobranch=1"

